# Accepting POST requests using Angular when invoked from a Server

Tags: java, angular, spring, post, http-post

I am using Angular app at front-end where this app can be invoked by using both GET and POST calls.
GET is invoked when user calls a URL from browser and POST is invoked by some other application to view home screen of Angular app.
When i refereed to some articles it is suggesting to use **Angular universal app** but this app can't be used in Production which is stated during app start.
Please suggest if there is any valid solution which can apply to Production as well.

Comment: Can you provide some code and screenshots?

Comment: I don't think there is any specific code, it just plain Angular app which will be invoked by some server application.